# How would I make the material for these LED headlights in Eevee?

Tags: eevee-render-engine

[image]

I've been trying to make an LED light similar to the one showed above, but I can't find a way to make the glass material be simultaneously transparent and emissive like in the picture. I tried making the glass itself emit light, but it looks really dull compared to the picture. I also tried making the top and bottom faces of a cube emit light, but that doesn't light up the glass in between. (Picture is in rendered view below).

[image]

The glass texture is just a principiled BSDF with full transparency, yellowish base color, and everything else set to 0, and the lit up planes are just yellow emissions of strength 10 with a gradient texture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here. Try something like this. EEVEE doesn't really play nicely with the Glass BSDF all the time, so you often have to find workarounds for good looking "shiny transparencies". In the shader below, I omitted the Glass shader, in lieu of a combination of shaders (many of which make up the glass shader anyway). I angled my screenshot so you can see reflection from my HDRI of the surface, showing it is indeed "shiny". Make sure to pay attention to the Blend Mode options I have highlighted on the right:

[image: Light]